# CASCADE behaviour on the drop of a foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, cascade, alter-table

I am not clear about what happens when a "foreign key constraint" is deleted specifying the option CASCADE.

For instance, consider this command

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT foreignKeyToTable2 CASCADE.
```

What the option CASCADE is supposed to do in this case? What would happen if I omitted it? And if I wrote RESTRICT instead of CASCADE?

Note: this example of query is excerpted from "Ramez Elmasri, Shamkant B. Navathe - Fundamentals of database systems, end of chapter 5".

Comment: I think explaining how foreign keys work is too broad a question.  Database documentation usually covers this pretty well, and the ideas are pretty much the same across databases.  Here is the MySQL documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I studied how foreign keys works, but I can't figure what the keyword CASCADE should delete. I mean, if I create a foreign key from table1 referring to table2 and then I delete table2 using the CASCADE keyword, then the foreign key will be deleted. If I was a DBMS I would delete nothing after the execution the command ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT foreignKeyToTable2 CASCADE.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using no specific DBMS, so I know that the answer may vary according to the implementation. But I can't understand which should be a sensate implementation. My idea is that the CASCADE keyword, in this case, is useless.

Comment: What I can't figure is an example of "an integrity constraints that depend on a foreign key integrity constraint".

Comment: @LucaMarconato . . . If you don't have cascade and you try to delete a parent record, then it will fail because the children are referring to it.  There is no "specific" example:  this occurs with pretty much every foreign key relationship.

Comment: @LucaMarconato: if you drop a primary key constraint you need the `cascade` to drop the referencing foreign keys as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cascade` option to drop a constraint is only needed when dropping **primary** keys, not when dropping a foreign key.

Consider this example in Postgres:

```
create table t1 (id integer, constraint pk_one primary key (id));
create table t2 (id integer primary key, id1 integer references t1);
```

When you try to run:

```
alter table t1 drop constraint pk_one;
```

You get:

```
ERROR: cannot drop constraint pk_one on table t1 because other objects depend on it
  Detail: constraint t2_id1_fkey on table t2 depends on index pk_one
  Hint: Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

If you run:

```
alter table t1 drop constraint pk_one cascade;
```

you get:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to constraint t2_id1_fkey on table t2
```

Telling you that the foreign key that needed the primary key was dropped as well.

---

Note that not all DBMS support a cascading drop. Postgres and Oracle do.
MySQL, SQL Server or Firebird do not. You need to drop the foreign keys manually in those DBMS.

Comment: Thank you! So the example in the book was incorrect!

Comment: @LucaMarconato. The syntax is correct for Postgres and Oracle. It's just not necessary when dropping a foreign key.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the "drop cascades to constraint" notice